# How to create dynamic multiple fields in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have angular js app. i am adding multiple dynamic fields inside that particular form.i have try like this

js file look like this

```
$scope.commonData = [{
    'a': '',
    'b': '',
}];

$scope.commonFormField = {
    service: [],
    exeName: []
};

$scope.submitCommonData = function() {
    // console.log($scope.commonFormField);
    console.log($scope.commonData);
    event.preventDefault();
}
$scope.addNewData = function() {
    $scope.commonData.push({
        'a': '',
        'b': '',
    });
}
$scope.removeCommonData = function(z) {
    $scope.commonData.splice(z, 1);
}
$scope.addNewFields = function() {
    $scope.commonFormField.serviceName.push('');
};
$scope.removeFields = function(z) {
    $scope.commonFormField.serviceName.splice(z, 1);
};
```

html look like this

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                      <a ng-click="addNewData()" href="javascript:void(0)">Add Common Data</a>
                      <form name="commonServicesForm" ng-submit="submitCommonServie();" role="form">
                        <div class="box-body" data-ng-repeat="Data in commonData track by $index" style="border: 1px dotted #000; margin-top:10px">
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click=removeCommonData($index);>x</button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <label for="" class="control-label">a</label>
                            <input type="text" required ng-model="Data.a[$index]"  class="form-control">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <label for="" class="control-label">b</label>
                            <input type="text" required ng-model="Data.b[$index]"  class="form-control">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                              <fieldset data-ng-repeat="field in commonFormField.serviceName track by $index2+$index">
                                   <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="" class="control-label">Service Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" required ng-model="commonFormField.serviceName[$index2+$index]" name="serviceName" id="vmName" placeholder="Enter Service name" class="form-control">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="" class="control-label">Exe name</label>
                                    <input type="text" required ng-model="commonFormField.exeName[$index2+$index]" name="exeName" id="exeName" placeholder="Enter Exe name" class="form-control">
                                  </div>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="removeFields($index2+$index)">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> REMOVE
                                  </button>
                              </fieldset>
                              <a ng-click="addNewFields()" href="javascript:void(0)">Add more service</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
```

The problem is `addNewData` function is working properly but the other function `addNewFields` is not working properly.

`addNewFields` is working fine when there is only one replica of html but when we create new replica of the html by clicking on `addNewData` then click on new generated html button of `addNewFields` its add new fields in both set of html means previous one also have new fields new html have same fields.

Comment: Use [Angular Formly](http://angular-formly.com). You will not regret it.

Comment: can you provide working fiddle or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the issue.
but your JSON object looks like that:

```
$scope.commonFormField = {
service: [],
exeName: []
```

};

and your HTML using field called: serviceName

```
<fieldset data-ng-repeat="field in commonFormField.serviceName track by $index2+$index">
```